# Show database fields name based on value

Tags: php, mysql

I have database like this :
[The database is have same value (matthew) but in different fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0tjK.png)

I would like to make a search box using HTML and PHP, when i input 'matthew', it's show like this :
[when i search 'matthew' it's show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tegB.png)

My Question is what query to use to select this value and show fields name where the 'matthew' value is in?

Here are my little code :

```html
<?php
$search='matthew';
$sql = mysql_query("select * from test where test.field_1 like '%$search%' or test.field_2 like '%$search%' or test.field_3 like '%$search%' order by id");
?>

<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>Field</b></td>
  </tr>
<?php
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

{ ?>  
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

but I don't know how to show field name where the value is in.

Comment: Can you please provide some code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Bryan //my query to search like this, table name is 'test'    
$sql = mysql_query("select * from test where test.field_1 like '%$search%' or test.field_2 like '%$search%' or test.field_3 like '%$search%'") or die(mysql_error());      but i have no idea to show the fields name.

Comment: please edit your post to include your code

Comment: possible duplicate of: *"the OP needs to read tutorials instead of asking us how to code it for them"*.

Comment: @Clayton I've added it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've read and try some tutorial but still didn't get it, I'm newbie at this

Comment: if you're looking for an exact name, which seems to be the case, don't use LIKE, use `=` without the percent signs. There are others ways of doing this, such as DISTINCT, GROUP BY, COUNT() etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Later I'll make search box so that would be not exact name, i've added my code to my question, I still can't figure out how to show the fields name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your code from the comments (though i would recommend using PDO instead as `mysql_*` is deprecated and unsecure)

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from test where test.field_1 like '%$search%' or test.field_2 like '%$search%' or test.field_3 like '%$search%'");

// i don't remember how fetching works in mysql_, i think something like this..
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

foreach($results as $column_name => $value){
    // check for the string
    if(strpos($value, "mike") === false) continue; // or whatever, use the variable that contains the searched text instead of "mike"

    echo "result was found in the $column_name column. The full value of that column is $value";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond @Pamblam, i would learn how to use PDO instead of mysql.
The code you're given was not answer my question, I need it like the image I post

Comment: it does answer your question. the column name is returned with every associatively fetched result as the key. you could maybe use the information schema if you really really really need to use Sql, however, that's asinine as the column name is already returned with every query.

Comment: if you would like to claim your points please hit the checkmark by my answer. if you want to be stubborn and insist that there is a better way,  that's fine too. good luck to you.

Comment: your answer show all the field name, if I search 'matthew', it show all field name, but if I search 'dan' it's still show all field name, it should be only show field name where 'dan' is in.

Comment: ugh.. so check for the string before echoing if you only want to show the matched columns... i'll update the answer

Comment: I didn't get how to show the field name based on the matched columns, that was my question.

Comment: well if you tried my code you would know how. it's right in front of you.

Comment: `foreach($results as $column_name => $value){` hmm, i wonder what's in the `$column_name` variable.

Comment: I've tried your code when you give it, I'm gonna take a look again

Comment: If You wonder what's in the $column_name, that show the field name, but I'm still wondering how to only show field name based on the matched columns

Comment: i showed you that too. let me know if you have any new questions.

Comment: Emm maybe i should take a long look at your code, I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I figure out the answer.

Comment: be sure to check the comments as well. strpos checks to see if the result exists in that specific column and `continue` means skip to the next column. so that is the line you want to look at. good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pamblam

Comment: Glad to have helped.